# emacs session attach back

Tags: emacs

When I was at VIM age, I used to enjoy working with screen which gives me the flexibility to switch between mulitple windows. And later I switched to emacs but I lost one of my favorite feature: screen session - when my putty window accidentally dies, all my windows are still there, if I attach back everything is there.

in emacs, I can also open quite a few different screens and switch between them, the thing is when my putty window is closed, everything there is gone. I would hope that I can attach back to the emacs I am working on, and I am pretty sure this monster can achieve this, any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run emacs in screen, just like vim. For keys that conflict, such as `C-a`, you can use `C-a a` inside of screen to send the `C-a` to emacs. Another option is to run emacs in [server mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html). You can do this by launching emacs with `--daemon`. You can then connect to the emacs daemon with `emacsclient`.

```
emacs --daemon       # start the server
emacsclient filename # open a file in the server
emacsclient -c       # connect to the server without opening a new file
```

Comment: Under X Window `M-x close-display-connection` close Emacs without leaving server.